# backbone.js - listing models contained in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Tried the following:

```
var collectionList = users.fetch();
alert(collectionList);
```

This returns null despite there being models in it.

Update - this worked for me:

```
users.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log(users.toJSON());
    },
    error: function() {
        // something is wrong..
    }
});
```

Comment: The `success` function will be passed the collection, the response, and request options. Utilizing the collection being explicitly passed to the function may help make things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
users.fetch({
    success: function(response) {
        _.each(response.models, function(model) {
            //Do something with the model here
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You could say so yes. This is `underscore.js`. Its used internally by `backbone.js` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
users.fetch().then(function () {
    console.log(users.toJSON());
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: tried that code, didn't work, compiler complained that the function was undefined when I added the then in - if I removed that it would return null. Updated my answer, with code that does work - only works if you include success or error.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is an async method, so is empty upon being called, after you specify success and error you should be able to then list your models.

```
users.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log(users.toJSON());
    },
    error: function() {
        // something is wrong..
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also can

```
var that = this;
users.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response) {
        console.log(that.collection.toJSON());
    },
    error: function() {
        // something is wrong..
    }
});
```